# Dynamically bind error message along with a icon to a single jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have created a global jQuery dialog to display all error messages in the application. I am able to bind the error message to the dialog, however I am unable to show the icon along with. For sake of simplicity I have provided a sample with a generic google image.

Any leads will be appreciated or if there's a better way to do it please do mention. Thanks in advance

```js
function showAlertDialog(message) {
            var $dialog = $('#ErrorMessageDialog')
                   .html(message)
                   .dialog({
                       modal: true,
                       title: 'Data Error!',
                       width: 400,
                       buttons: {
                           Ok: function () {
                               $(this).dialog('close');
                           }
                       }
                       
                   });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }
        
        $("#btnOk").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Ok is clicked');
        });
        
        $("#btnCancel").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Cancel is clicked');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="ErrorMessageDialog" style="display:none;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/></td>/*display icon*/
                <td></td>/*display error message*/
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<input type="button" id="btnOk" value="OK"/>
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the specific table cell you want to update. Consider using Class selector.

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  function showAlertDialog(ttl, msg) {
    var $dialog = $('#ErrorMessageDialog')
      .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: ttl,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close').dialog("destroy");
          }
        }
      });
    $('.message', $dialog).html(msg);
    $dialog.dialog('open');
  }

  $("#btnOk").click(function() {
    showAlertDialog('Alert!', 'Ok is clicked');
  });

  $("#btnCancel").click(function() {
    showAlertDialog('Alert!', 'Cancel is clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btnOk" value="OK" />
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />

<div id="ErrorMessageDialog" style="display:none;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="icon"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png" /></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant!! This helps

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are replacing the content of `#ErrorMessageDialog` with only message. You should target the required `td` element not the whole `#ErrorMessageDialog` when associating the message. Sample code will be like:

```
function showAlertDialog(message) {
            var $dialog = $('#ErrorMessageDialog .target')
                   .html(message)
                   .dialog({
                       modal: true,
                       title: 'Data Error!',
                       width: 400,
                       buttons: {
                           Ok: function () {
                               $(this).dialog('close');
                           }
                       }

                   });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }

        $("#btnOk").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Ok is clicked');
        });

        $("#btnCancel").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Cancel is clicked');
        });
```

==

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="ErrorMessageDialog" style="display:none;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/></td>/*display icon*/
                <td class="target"></td>/*display error message*/
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<input type="button" id="btnOk" value="OK"/>
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"/>
```

Here I am targeting `.target` class which I have given to the target `td` element where you want to associate the message.

Comment: I am still not seeing the icon.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showAlertDialog(message) {
var img='<img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/>';
            var $dialog = $('#ErrorMessageDialog')
                   .html(message+img)
                   .dialog({
                       modal: true,
                       title: 'Data Error!',
                       width: 400,
                       buttons: {
                           Ok: function () {
                               $(this).dialog('close');
                           }
                       }
                       
                   });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        }
        
        $("#btnOk").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Ok is clicked');
        });
        
        $("#btnCancel").click(function(){
        showAlertDialog('Cancel is clicked');
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="ErrorMessageDialog" style="display:none;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-1-6584893165273088-res.png"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<input type="button" id="btnOk" value="OK"/>
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"/>
```

append the image along with dialog message.

Comment: If you append image, you will loose any formatting you might have under "ErrorMessageDialog" id element, in the sample, the OP has a table which will be lost.

Comment: Dialog plugin(jqueryUI) will remove child elements

Comment: I can see the icon but, I am losing the table formatting