# Click event in a popup (Click on popup-picture or button)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet

I want to show a bigger image from a image inside a popup when image or button clicked

I found this example from mapbox  [clicks in popup](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/clicks-in-popups/)

In this example a alert pops up but i want to get a new "popup" with a bigger image. I think I have to replace the alert with a jquery ui dialog or similar.

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({minHeight: 300,minWidth:830});
```

I changed the code a bit so I use jquery ui and leafletjs instead of mapboxjs. It works the same so far. But how I can replace the alert?

I am not a coder more a hunter-gatherers.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

....

```
var marker = L.marker([43.6475, -79.3838])
.bindPopup('<button class="trigger">Say hi</button>')
.addTo(map);
$('#map').on('click', '.trigger', function() {
alert('Hello from Toronto!'); //replace alert
});
```

Comment: Put the `dialog()` call in the click handler where the `alert()` is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider the following, similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497284/how-to-replace-window-alert-with-jquery-ui-dialog-merging-two-scripts

Comment: This one also might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596132/dynamically-bind-error-message-along-with-a-icon-to-a-single-jquery-dialog